# slow loading for isotope jquery...why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I am in the process of creating an online portfolio and I am using the [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) jquery to present images on my site. The problem I'm having is that when you go to my site the content loads and sits for a second before self-organizing using the Isotope jquery.

I have 2 linked CSS files (one local and one on a separate hosted site), the latest Jquery (hosted on Jquery's site), and then the Isotope script (hosted locally). Is this amount of referencing files the cause of the slow self-organizing with the Isotope script? If I hosted all of these locally would it run faster?

Comment: i'm not an isotope user but have you try setting both height and width attributes for each image? Couldn't you wait all images being loaded before applying isotope plugin and showing them?

Comment: It looks like the site waits until everything is loaded to apply the isotope plugin. I'm using a script to preload the images. Perhaps it's the video on there that delays the isotope plugin but I want to find a solution without delaying the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are waiting until the whole page is loaded before setting up Isotope, the browser has to wait not just for the code to download, but also for all the elements to download, the images, the video player javascript and so on. So only when everything is ready is isotope moving stuff around: leading to the delay you see.

That may be necessary, if the size of all the content is only available after it has been loaded.

To improve performance.

1. Put explicit sizes on any content to be loaded (like images, video).
2. Move the jquery, isotope and isotope initialization script tags to the end of your HTML body.
3. Don't wrap the init in a document load handler.

Then what will happen is the HTML page will load first, then as all the images and other stuff are loading, the browser will load each of the script tags in order, when it has loaded isotope, it will call your init script which will arrange everything right then. Isotope will cope because everything it needs to know the size of has its size set, and as the browser continues to receive the resources it is loading, they'll appear in the correct location.

There are some good reasons for doing things in an onLoad handler, but often putting your scripts at the bottom of the page is just as good, unless your script needs any data coming in from other external files (like CSS, or images).

Comment: Could you elaborate on the 3rd point? I already have set sizes on all the content, and I moved my Javascript and Isotope (plus initialization) to the bottom, and it still is loading around the same times. Sorry for my ignorance, I've only been learning jquery and Javascript for a couple months.

Comment: Originally you only initialized isotope from inside a document onload handler, just remove that, and initialize in the top level of the script.